# jQuery Ajax - deserialize object to xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, knockout.js

I want to post data to my service and I have chosen XML instead of JSON because I have database logic that will query the xml.

So this is my code so far:

```
var saveChanges = function (agencyObservable) {

            if (agencyObservable) {
                var data = ko.toJS(agencyObservable._latestValue[0]);
                var options = {
                    url: '/breeze/SaveData',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'xml',
                    data: data,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }
            }
```

**Breeze.webapi**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public void SaveData(XmlDocument xmldoc)
        {

            tblAgencyQuery tblAgencyQuery = new tblAgencyQuery();
            tblAgencyQuery.QueryID = Guid.NewGuid();
            //tblAgencyQuery.QueryText = data.ToString();
            //tblAgencyQuery.AgencyID = DeserializedData.agencyID;
            tblAgencyQuery.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

            _ContextProvider.Context.tblAgencyQuery.Add(tblAgencyQuery);
            _ContextProvider.Context.Entry(tblAgencyQuery).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
            _ContextProvider.Context.SaveChanges();

        }
```

agencyObservable is knockout observable and I am converting it to a standard javaScript object. But I don't know what to do from here. I want to somehow change my object to XML but is this easy or possible?

Comment: AFAIK jQuery has no method for easy building of xml.
Also, is your question really related to knockout or jquery? Question is just "convert js object to xml", isn't it?

Comment: what server side are you using?its good to transfer data as json from client side and convert json to xml on server side

Comment: I am using Breeze.WebApi. I will add that to my post